# Firefox Jquery Calculation Bug

Tags: jquery, firefox

I have created a slider in jquery that moves `.slides-container` depending on the link clicked.  This works beautifully in every major browser(even ie9) except for Firefox(20.0).  The problem appears to be that Firefox ignores the padding of `.info-container` because when I disable the padding, everything works beautifully.  How do I tell jquery to acknowledge `.info-container`'s padding when making it's calculations without messing up the other browsers?  Anyone have ideas how to fix it?

**JS**

```
var contentwidth = parseInt($('.slides-content').innerWidth(), 10);
$('.slides-container').css({'width': $('.info-container').length*contentwidth});
$('.info-container').css({'width': contentwidth});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="slides-content clearfix">
                <div class="slides-container">
                    <div class="info-container me clearfix">
                        <div class="info"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem, aliquam amet minus porro animi assumenda error esse sit explicabo quam quisquam ipsum nihil dignissimos. Dolorem quisquam quaerat maiores ducimus optio.</p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-container pics clearfix">
                        <div class="info"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Corrupti, asperiores, fugit, necessitatibus officia facere tempora ad officiis sed est architecto voluptatibus enim in. Aspernatur amet fugiat repellat incidunt placeat voluptas.</p></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="info-container about clearfix">
                        <div class="info"><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quas, et perspiciatis quasi voluptatem maxime vero dolores iusto fugiat corporis ducimus cum at consectetur repellat culpa eius blanditiis ut? Eaque, assumenda?</p></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slides-content {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
}
.slides-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.info-container {
    padding: 35px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: #F8F8F8;
    color: #7F7F7F;
    font-size: 17px;
    float: left;
    line-height: 19px;
    font-weight: 300;
    .info {
        position: relative;
        float: left;
    }
}
```

**Error**
[image]
**Correct**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check if the inner width of info and info-container are same.

Comment: .info-container is 796, .info is 726